# Generate bounds from a dictionary of parameters

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, bounds

What I am trying to is I think specific, but I was wondering if somebody had an idea of how I can code something nice for doing what I want.

I am starting with a dictionary of this format:

```
inp = {
    "val1":{
        'param1':   [0.0, 0.003543809774418695, 0.0], 
        'param2':   [0.0, 0.04439156494695967, 0.0], 
        'param3':   [0.0, 0.27337841732514817, 1.0]
    },
    "val2":{
        'param1':   [0.0, 0.27704015849313185, 1.0], 
        'param2':   [0.0, 0.004835039503062099, 0.0], 
        'param3':   [0.0, 0.038987106843840116, 0.0]
    },
    "val3":{
        'param1':   [0.0, 0.02446316540346886, 0.0], 
        'param2':   [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
        'param3':   [0.0, 0.011166103115052235, 0.0]
    }

}
```

And what I want to output from this, is a another dictionary that would look like this:

```
bounds = {
    'param1':   [[min of first coordinate, max of first coordinate], [min of second coordinate, max  of second coordinate], [min  of third coordinate,max  of third coordinate]], 
    'param2':   [[min of first coordinate, max of first coordinate], [min of second coordinate, max  of second coordinate], [min  of third coordinate,max  of third coordinate]], 
    'param3':   [[min of first coordinate, max of first coordinate], [min of second coordinate, max  of second coordinate], [min  of third coordinate,max  of third coordinate]]
}
```

Concretely, I should end up with this for param1:

```
'param1':[[0.0,0.0],[0.003543809774418695,0.27704015849313185], [0.0,1.0]]
```

I am trying to have a nice and clean code but I am having troubles to find something at the moment...

The numbers of "val", "params" and length of the lists must be flexible...
Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but I think this does it:

```
# assumes each nested dict has identical keys
bounds = {}
prim_key = list(inp.keys())[0]
nested_keys = inp[prim_key].keys()
sec_key = list(nested_keys)[0]
list_length = len(inp[prim_key][sec_key])

for nested_key in nested_keys:
    bounds[nested_key] = []
    for coord in range(list_length):
        vals = [inp[d][nested_key][coord] for d in inp.keys()]
        bounds[nested_key].append([min(vals), max(vals)])

print(bounds)
```

Output:

```
{'param1': [[0.0, 0.0],
            [0.003543809774418695, 0.27704015849313185],
            [0.0, 1.0]],
 'param2': [[0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.04439156494695967],
            [0.0, 1.0]],
 'param3': [[0.0, 0.0],
            [0.011166103115052235, 0.27337841732514817],
            [0.0, 1.0]]}
```

Edit: this also assumes that the lists are all of equal length

Comment: Yep! It does what I want. Maybe not the prettiest indeed, but at least it works haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Final result is stored in bounds dictionary:

```
bounds={}
for dictionaryK, dictionaryV in inp.items():
    for key, item in dictionaryV.items():
        if key not in bounds.keys():
            bounds[key] = []
        bounds[key].append([min(item), max(item)])
```

Comment: Thank you but its not what I want to do. I want to have the corresponding min and max of each coordinate... I should have param1[0] = param2[0] = param3[0] = [0,0] for instance...